# Cookie was blocked because neither did the request URL's domain exactly | Next js and Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js13

I've developed a Node.js backend paired with a Next.js frontend. The Node.js backend is hosted on sub2.sub1.example.com, and the frontend is situated at sub1.example.com. To authenticate users, I employ a Next.js middleware that validates the token stored as a cookie on the client's computer.

Upon a user's login attempt, the cookie is set. However, during the redirection to the dashboard page, the cookie isn't send along with the get request to the next js server. Due to this the middleware redirects back [image]to login page.